# How to fix GRUB's "file not found." error

Tags: grub2

I see this:

```
GRUB loading.
Welcome to GRUB!

error:file not found.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue> _
```

I tried using the Windows installation disk but it didn't work.

I also tried reinstalling Kali or Debian but they didn't boot to the installation part and it also doesn't want to boot the original operating system.

Comment: Please don't type in all caps.  It appears as if you are yelling at us. And it's difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

- +live boot ubuntu or kali from usb

  - connect to the Internet
  - install `bootrepair` by using following process:
  - open a new Terminal, then type the following commands (press Enter after each line)

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

  +launch Boot-Repair from either :
  -the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
  -or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
  -Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then
  reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.

  If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help
  you by email or forum. [further on boot repair here][1]

  [1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair